# Meteor SimpleSchema + Methods : clicking too fast throw an error

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor

First, I have this schema:

```
Rides = new Mongo.Collection('Rides');

Rides.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
        name:{type:String},
        'passengers.$._id': {
            type: String,
            autoValue: function(){
                if(this.isUpdate && this.operator !== '$pull')
                    return this.userId;
                else
                    this.unset();
            }
        },
        'passengers.$.validate':{type:Boolean},
);
```

Server side, I have these methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
    leaveRide: function(_id){
        check(_id, String);
        Rides.update(_id, {
            $pull:{passengers:{
                _id:this.userId
            }}
        });
    },
    joinRide: function(_id){
        check(_id, String);
        Rides.update(_id, {
            $addToSet: {passengers: {validate:true}}
         });
    }
});
```

And finally, two buttons `Join` and `Leave` which call:

```
 Template.ride.events({
    'click .join': function(e){
        Meteor.call('joinRide', this.ride._id);
    },
    'click .leave': function(e){
        Meteor.call('leaveRide', this.ride._id);
    },
});
```

It works perfectly fine, problem is when I click too fast on buttons (one after another), it seems that the queries don't have time to process and I get:

Client-side (either of these):

> Error invoking Method 'leaveRide': Internal server error [500]
>   Error invoking Method 'joinRide': ID is required [400]

Server-side (either of these):

> Exception while invoking method 'leaveRide' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to 'leaveRide'
>   Exception while invoking method 'joinRide' Error: ID is required

Comment: I think a very good answer to this problem can be found here : https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/advanced-latency-compensation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of investigation, it turned out that it was the Easy Security Package that was preventing calls when clicking faster than 500ms between clicks (security against DDoS).

See : https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-security